# Im trying to clear all the values of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

So I was trying to make the entire array = 0 but it's not working out. Every time I run this gives me an index out of bounds error. the reason the array is so big is because I plan to make it so that you can increase SquareNum. This is in Java by the way.

```java
int squareNum = 7
int[][] chipHere = new int[100][100]
chipClear();
```

My chipClear method is the following:

```java
public void chipClear() {
    for( int i = 0; i < squareNum; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; i < squareNum - 1; j++) {
            chipHere[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you code as a logical error, the condition `(int j = 0; i < squareNum - 1; j++)` may be not reachable

Answer (score 4):

You're using `i` instead of `j` in the inner loop:

```
for(int j = 0; i < squareNum - 1; j++)
```

should be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < squareNum - 1; j++)
```

It's a good idea to *not* use `i` and `j` together because they're visually similar. If this is a 2D array then consider using the names `x` and `y` or `row` and `col`.

Comment: Using "it's a good idea to not" instead of "it's a bad idea to" is actually a really smart language trick

Comment: @byxor I was originally going to put "it's a good idea to use `x` and `y` instead of `i` and `j`" but I realised that the best variable names depend on the context, for example an array-of-arrays used for a hashtable with chaining (rather than linear-probing) you wouldn't use `x` and `y` even though structurally it's the same.